# Nothing published to /scan under Hydro

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After updating to Hydro, executing:

`roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch`

no longer seems to work correctly.

The expected topics appear, and it is possible to get some data off the Kinect: images and pointcloud data can be visualized in rviz.  However, nothing is being published to the \scan topic.

Everything seems to work fine if I grab a copy of the Groovy version of 3dsensor.launch and launch that.

The issue is the same whether I use a Kinect or Asus Xtion.

Has anyone else had luck with 3dsensor.launch under Hydro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112391/nothing-published-to-/scan-under-hydro/) by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2013-12-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/scan topic may not work with the default 3dsensor.launch setup.

Try this.

> 3dsensor.launch depth_registration:=false

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2013-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) on 2013-12-30**:
Thanks! That solves the problem. Is there any reason this defaults to true?  According to the documentation for openni_launch: "If true, use OpenNI's factory-calibrated depth->RGB registration", but it defaults to false for openni_launch.  What is the practical impact of leaving it off?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-30**:
It changes the type of output you get. With false, you get just depth clouds which are lower bandwidth and come out on a different topic. Changing it will break anyone using the old settings.

**Comment by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) on 2014-01-02**:
Good to know.  I think this should be considered a bug in 3dsensor.launch.  It will be confusing for users if different topics are "broken" based on a configuration setting.  It's also inconsistent with the behavior in Groovy.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-01-02**:
Create a ticket on github and when people have time they can check. I remember originally setting up 3dsensor.launch in groovy so everything was on and 'viewable' from rviz (but you shouldn't use it like this because it's cpu hungry), so it might be a regression.

**Comment by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) on 2014-01-03**:
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues/123

**Comment by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on 2014-01-15**:
I tried the solution above. when I use depth_registration=false, I don't get the PointCloud2 output on rviz.